# Data cleaning in Google forms

Tags: google-forms

I've recently conducted a survey using Google Forms. The graphs and charts in the summary section are enough for me. However, I want to clean 10% of data (change ambiguous answers). Is there an easy way to do this using the spreadsheet that is connected with the form?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet and example of your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, there isn't an "easy way" like using a built-in feature but you could use Google Apps Script, an add-on or a third party app.

If you will go for Google Apps Script, you should know about JavaScript and the Google Forms way of making Google Forms question to Google Sheets column mapping. Most of the questions are mapped 1 to 1 but grid questions are mapped 1 to many, where many is the number of question option rows.